# Populate a Contribution form custom field from a URL parameter

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page, hooks

I know I can do it using `civicrm_buildForm` but I don't know:

- How to get the custom field
- How to set the value to this field

Comment: What is your civicrm version?

Comment: @PradeepNayak 5.65.1

Comment: Are you talking about offline contribution form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like below
you can use API4 to get the exact machine names

civicrm/api4#/explorer/CustomField/get?select=%5B"id"%5D&where=%5B%5B"name","%3D",""%5D,%5B"custom_group_id:name","%3D",""%5D%5D&limit=0&checkPermissions=0&_index="0"

```
function extname_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main') {
    if (isset($_GET['custom_59'])) {
      $customFieldId = \Civi\Api4\CustomField::get(FALSE)
        ->addSelect('id')
        ->addWhere('name', '=', 'is_eligible')
        ->addWhere('custom_group_id:name', '=', 'gift_aid')
        ->execute()
        ->first()['id'] ?? NULL;
      if (!empty($customFieldId)) {
        $form->setDefaults([
          'custom_' . $customFieldId => $_GET['custom_59'],
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PradeepNayak. However 59 is the custom field ID, right? My local env database is different from the prod database, so I need to get this custom field without using its ID. It's possible?

Comment: If you are using the same machine name then yes possible.